# Also get inherited fields of CXXRecordDecl

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-tidy

Is it possible to get all fields that are defined explicitly and implicitly (inherited from parent classes) apart from iterating over a CXXRecordDecl's bases recursively and evaluating along the way, using C++'s inheritance and access rules, whether a given member of a base class is accessible in the class I started searching for members?

This procedure is really cumbersome and not straight-forward - it seems like there must be a more intuitive and simple solution using existing implementations of LLVM/clang to this problem.

Thank you in advance!